# Python set a column in list of list 2D matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, tuples

So given two lists

```
y_new = (   165,     152,     145,    174)
pos_2D  = ( (2,3), (32,52), (73,11), (43,97) )
```

I would like to so something like

```
pos_2D_new = setCol(2, y_new, pos_2D)
```

where column 2 is the Y coordinate.

```
pos_2D_new = ( (2,165), (32,152), (73,145), (43,174) )
```

How to set a 1D into a 2D tuple in Python?

Comment: So you replace the second part of the tuple with `y_new`? What happens with the "old" second item?

Comment: Yes... I am creating a new tuple, with the the old X, and a new Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
pos_2D_new = [ (x, y2) for (x, _), y2 in zip(pos_2D, y_new) ]
```

or if you want a tuple:

```
pos_2D_new = tuple((x, y2) for (x, __), y2 in zip(pos_2D, y_new))
```

We thus concurrently iterate over the `pos_2D` and `ynew`, and each time we construct a new tuple `(x, y2)`.

The above is of course not very generic, we can make it more generic, and allow to specify what item to replace, like:

```
def replace_coord(d, old_pos, new_coord):
    return tuple(x[:d] + (y,) + x[d+1:] for x, y in zip(old_pos, new_coord))
```

So for the *x*-coordinate you can use `replace_coord(0, old_pos, new_x_coord)` whereas for the *y*-coordinate it is `replace_coord(1, old_pos, new_y_coord)`. This also works for coordinates in three or more dimensions.

Comment: Thanks Willem! Amazing!... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression with `zip`:

```
pos_2D_new = tuple((x, y) for (x, _), y in zip(pos_2D, y_new))
```

With your sample input, `pos_2D_new` would become:

```
((2, 165), (32, 152), (73, 145), (43, 174))
```

Answer (score 0):

Which would give

```
def setCol(idx, coords_1d, coords_nd):
    # recalling that indexing starts from 0
    idx -= 1
    return [
        c_nd[:idx] + (c_1d,) + c_nd[idx+1:]
        for (c_1d, c_nd) in zip(coords_1d, coords_nd)
    ]
```

and

```
>>> setCol(2, y_new, pos_2D)
[(2, 165), (32, 152), (73, 145), (43, 174)]
```